# google.maps.event.trigger not working. followed all the relevant previous answers

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to trigger a click event for a marker on Google maps to bring up an `infowindow` on it.

```
$li.click(function(e) { 
    var checkmarker = this.id;
    for (var i in markers) {
        if (checkmarker == markers[i].id) {
            google.maps.event.trigger(markers[i], 'click');          
        }
    }       
}); 

$("#addresses ul").append($li);
```

I have added an event listener like this:

```
(function(marker, data) {
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function (e) {
        var contentString = "<p><img width='80' src='http://science-all.com/images/flower/flower-06.jpg'/>" + marker.title + "</p>";
        infoWindow.setContent(contentString);
        infoWindow.open(map, marker);
    });
})(marker, data);
```

Please tell me what I am missing here. When I click on the `li` its comparing properly with marker id, but its not able to pass the correct marker object I guess.

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the issue

Comment: I get a javascript error with the code as posted: `Uncaught TypeError: (intermediate value) is not a function`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to look at the [Simple click event](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/event-simple) in the Maps documentation.

I noticed that you have a different way of setting the marker click event. Use the [Marker.addListener](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Marker) syntax to properly set it.

In the example, it should look like this

```
...
marker.addListener('click', function() {
    [do something here]
});
...
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try this

```
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
content: contentString
});

var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
position: uluru,
map: map,
title: 'Example title'
});
marker.addListener('click', function() {
infowindow.open(map, marker);
});
```

more info on

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/infowindow-simple

Comment: Thanks, but this is the basic you are providing. I needed info-window for every marker on clicking respective link.